# Can equipment always be repaired?

Tags: dark-souls

[The original IGN review](https://www.ign.com/articles/2011/09/30/dark-souls-review) ([archived page](https://web.archive.org/web/20230830124813/https://www.ign.com/articles/2011/09/30/dark-souls-review)) has the following claim (to be mindful of spoilers, I've edited out the boss description):

> One of the mid-game bosses, meanwhile, emits corrosive bile that swiftly degrades your equipment if you get
> stuck in its flow, potentially leaving you standing naked in front of [the said enemy] with a broken sword.
> There's no way to repair weapons and armor once they've been completely destroyed, so it's possible to lose
> all your best gear in this battle.

"no way to repair weapons and armor once they've been completely destroyed" ... I'm not aware of any equipment this applies to (excluding consumables) outside of the crystal weapons. Blacksmiths, the repairbox and repair powder can fix broken items.

Note that the page has been edited, long after the *Artorias of the Abyss*  DLC  and the remaster release in 2018.

Comment: To those having read an earlier paragraph: the  curse debuff no longer stacks, was changed in an update.

Answer (score 1):

The [fandom wiki](https://darksouls.fandom.com/wiki/Repair_Powder) is a better place to find the on the souls series. The IGN guides can be a bit... [misleading](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D6lClIybJ6Y)

In short, yes the Repair Powder does repair Broken items. However, it only repairs the item held in your right hand (I.e. your main weapon)<sup>[TBC]</sup>. You can repair an off-hand weapon/shield, by swapping it to your main hand, then using the repair powder, but this is getting a bit fidgety in the heat of combat...

If your armour breaks, you'll need to take it to a blacksmith, or repair it using the [Repairbox](https://darksouls.fandom.com/wiki/Repairbox) at a bonfire.

The [Repair Spell](https://darksouls.fandom.com/wiki/Repair) however, does apply to equipped armour as well as the right hand weapon.

Comment: I didn't reference an IGN guide or a wiki page, but their initial DS1 review.